# How to set the Android status bar color while loading (or in splashscreen) in Ionic?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have installed `cordova-splashscreen` Plugin and set this on my `config.xml`

```
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#1FBBA5" />
```

But the status bar is black until the deviceReady ready event fires and I can change it programatically.

Is there a way to set this on start so the color of the status bar has that hex value when the splash screen is showed?

Edit:

Following @eatmeimadanish advice I have created a `style.xml` file and linked it to my `AndroidManifest.xml` and the first moment the app loads it takes the color I choose (in this case and just for test an ugly yellow) but the moment the splash screen appears it goes back to black.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="25" android:versionName="0.0.25" package="com.my.app" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@style/MyStatusBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <service android:name="com.homerours.musiccontrols.MusicControlsNotificationKiller" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyStatusBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">#ffff00</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I have tried to put it in the `application` tag too but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to change the theme in AndroidManifest.xml.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html

Comment: Hi, @eatmeimadanish I have updated the question. I followed your advice but it just works halfway.

Comment: If it's going back to black, then either your statusbar plugin is activating and turning it back, or you should activate it and still use it.  The Android Manifest is basically what it looks at during the launch, and then cordova takes over.  So you will probably need to leverage both.